# Renaming a file including Great-grandparent, grandparent and parent in the filename excluding Calls folder

Tags: powershell

I have searched for a similar solution online but still cannot get this working.
I would like to include the great-grandparent, grandparent and parent folder name (ignoring the calls folder) in the pdf file name see below:

Current path:

```
C:\AttachedFiles\Test01\Calls\1848953\1\engineer_jobsheet.pdf
C:\AttachedFiles\Teoo233\Calls\185864\3\engineer_jobsheet.pdf
```

Would like to rename the pdf file as shown below (excludes calls folder):

```
Test01_1848953_1_engineer_jobsheet.pdf
Teoo233_185864_3_engineer_jobsheet.pdf
```

I have started with this which renames the pdf file to 1_engineer_jobsheet.pdf.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\AttachedFiles\ -Filter engineer_jobsheet.pdf -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name+'_'+$_.Name}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to do this excluding the calls folder name (bear in mind test01/Teoo233 can be named differently in each time)

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your paths have the same number of folders you can use `-split`.

Try splitting the paths by the "\" character and combine them as you please. Something like below...

```
$directory = Get-ChildItem C:\AttachedFiles\ -Filter engineer_jobsheet.pdf -Recurse

Foreach($file -in $directory){
    $string = $file.fullname -split "\\" #splits path
    $newstring = $string[2]+"_"+$string[4]+"_"+$string[5]+"_"+$string[6] #recreates string
    Rename-Item $file.fullname -NewName $newstring
}
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem C:\AttachedFiles\ -Filter engineer_jobsheet.pdf -Recurse | %{
    [string]$path = $_.fullname
    $string = $path -split "\\" #splits path
    $newstring = $string[2]+"_"+$string[4]+"_"+$string[5]+"_"+$string[6] #recreates string
    Rename-Item $path -NewName $newstring
}
```

Comment: `$String[6]` still contains the extension, so no need to append it **again**. Easier: `$newstring = $_.FullName.split('\')[2,4,5,6] -join '_'` Instead of burying the file deep in the sub folders it may be wiser to `$_ | Move-Item -Dest (Join-Path "C:\AttachedFiles" $newstring)`

Comment: ah yes! didnt know you could do `... [2,4,5,6] -join '_'`. Good one!

Comment: Thank you both, that worked exactly how  I wanted it too.

Comment: @Laali Thats great news. If it resolves your problem please be sure to mark it as your answer by clicking the checkmark. This lets others know for future reference.